# UserNotifications framework and application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:

Tags: ios

We're in the process of dropping iOS 9 support, which means adopting the UserNotifications framework introduced in iOS 10.

It's not clear from Apple's documentation (surprise) how `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` and UserNotifications relate to each other. From what I can tell, it appears they're suggesting an either or approach.

The issue is that our app uses `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` to prefetch data while the app is in the background, in order to avoid any network delays when the user actually taps the notification. The UserNotifications framework does not support any background operations. Our app also needs to support user actions, so we're left having to implement both `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` and the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, which is rather frustrating.

I'm hopeful someone here knows Apple's intentions. Is Apple trying to discourage people from prefetching data while the app is in the background? Or will UserNotifications support background operations in a fututure iOS release? (still nothing in iOS 11, so I'm not hopeful). Is `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` now only intended for silent notifications?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?
I think the application delegate method is still left for prefetching, while the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods are for handling presentation and user responses.